# Angular 2 with CLI using JIT for translation

Tags: angular, angular-cli, jit

I am trying to get the [Angular 2 i18n translation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#jit) running using jit. Unfortunately I get an Error saying, that the variable "System" is not defined. So I downloaded it from npm. I included it in angular-cli.json so it gets loaded. But the scriptblock in the index.html is loaded before the System variable is declared.

```
<script>
  // Get the locale id somehow
document.locale = 'de-de';

// Map to the text plugin
System.config({
  map: {
    text: 'systemjs-text-plugin.js'
  }
});

// Launch the app
System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

How can i fix this?